# App.config in C# and VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, app-config

What is the difference between a C#.net project's app.config file and vb.net Project's app.config file. I have project in C# which is working correctly .. But when i converted the same to VB.net, the app.config file settings are creating issue, as it is not working as expected. I just copy- pasted the XML settings to vb.net project's app config, but still it is not working.. Any suggestion

*(Note, edit: The relevant section from the config-file, copied from the comment below for clarity):*

```
<trace autoflush="true"/>
    <sources>
        <source name="Logger" >
            <listeners>
                <add name="eventlogListener" 
                     type="System.Diagnostics.EventLogTraceListener" 
                     initializeData="Application">
                    <filter type="System.Diagnostics.EventTypeFilter" 
                            initializeData="Error"/>
                </add>
                <add name="textfileListener"
                     type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" 
                     initializeData="ErrorLog.log" />
                <remove name="Default"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>
```

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get an exception when trying to run the program? Does the program just do something unexpected, something else?

Comment: What I tried is to log application error in to a File as well as event log using tracelistnhers. the same worked perfectly in C#, and eventhough the application is running and not showing any exception in VB.NET , it is not logging trace errors to file/event viewer.

Comment: Could you please post the config file (at least the part where you define the log configuration) I suspect you have a log file name with C# escaping

Comment: You might need to look at a slightly different route. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480108/how-do-i-programmatically-determine-the-location-of-the-vb-application-log

Answer (score -3):

i think there are much difference between the c# and vb.net app.config by the way app.config is XML configuration :)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client"/>
</startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: -1. Answers on StackOverflow are expected to be supported by facts, such as links to official documentation or other answers on SO. Another thing is that `i think there are much difference` is hardly an answer to `What is the difference`. Code fragment is irrelevant.